# How to solve deadlock in this program?

Tags: go

I am new to golang, so this deadlock issue is unknown for me. I've been Reading some articles, but it seems to be a quick fix in this program.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

//ping
func addValue(input1 int, input2 int, chn2 chan<- int) {
    chn2 <- input1 + input2
}

//pong
//function to write 1st user input to channel_1
func getUserInput(input1 int, input2 int, chn2 <-chan int, chn1 chan int, chn3 chan int) {
    chn1 <- input1
    chn1 <- input2
    //receiving info from other func and read into this func.
    val := <-chn2
    chn3 <- val
}

//Main function
func main() {
    var input1 int
    var input2 int
    chn1 := make(chan int, 3)
    chn2 := make(chan int)
    chn3 := make(chan int)

    //taking inputs from terminal
    fmt.Scanln(&input1)
    fmt.Scan(&input2)

    //calling go functions
    go getUserInput(input1, input2, chn1, chn2, chn3)
    go addValue(input1, input2, chn2)

    //shifting values from channels to var.
    /*x:=
      y :=
      z := <-chn3*/

    //print out the values on the terminal
    fmt.Println("Reading first input: ", <-chn1)
    fmt.Println("Reading second input: ", <-chn1)
    fmt.Println("Giving resulted value: ", <-chn3)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had function argument order wrong. Just change the function header and you are good

Change

```
func getUserInput(input1 int, input2 int, chn2 <-chan int, chn1 chan int, chn3 chan int) {
```

to

```
func getUserInput(input1 int, input2 int, chn1 chan int,chn2 <-chan int,  chn3 chan int) {
```

Play link :https://play.golang.com/p/3lKLoEytr9J

Comment: I am bit Wonder func getUserInput receiving value from func addvalue isn't !! because I thought it should get result through channel 2 ! 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the method `getUserInput` you are passing the channels chn1 and chn2 in the wrong position. Please replace the method calls like this `go getUserInput(input1, input2, chn2, chn1, chn3)` or switch the position in the method.

Comment: Thanks for replying:-D